# What's the difference between Boost.MPI and Boost.Interprocess?

Tags: c++, boost

I suppose `Boost.MPI` and `Boost.Interprocess` are different, right?

From a performance perspective, which is faster? Has anyone ever done benchmarking?

Can I use them to pass data within the same process (i.e. among different threads)?

Thanks!

Comment: "I suppose they are different, right?" - No, the boost developers where just bored one day and said: "Hey, lets write that again!" ;)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

They are totally different.  Boost MPI is for parallel/distributed computing (like massively-parallel super-computers).  It requires an existing installation of MPI (Message Passing Interface), such as OpenMPI.  MPI is usually used with high-performance clusters of networked computers, or with super computers.  The Boost MPI library is basically just a nice wrapper around the normal MPI function calls.

Boost.Interprocess, on the other hand, is an API for IPC (Interprocess Communications), i.e. communicating between two processes on a single computer.

If you want to share data between processes on the same computer, Boost.Interprocess is useful.  But if, as you suggest, you just want to share data between *threads*, you don't need any of this.  You just need a threading API.